# Running an unzipped multifile addon from the init file

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I have code setup so it's in multiple .py files and referenced in the init file and would like to know if there's a way to run the folder without zipping the file. Just seems tedious to do without every update.

When I try to run the init file from the test editor without zipping, I get this error:
"ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package."

Comment: You can directly install an addon as a `.py` file, if all your addon code fits inside this file

Comment: I've adjusted my question to clarify that my script is in multiple files. This is what I meant by modular. @Gorgious

Comment: I did not understand this, and I’ve been pretty good at both blender and python. In the very first sentence, which file are you trying to avoid zipping?

Comment: You can directly install an addon by copying the folder containing the \_\_init\_\_.py into the addon directory. (You can also symlink it if it's in a git repo.) Is that what you want?

Comment: @scurest That sounds like the solution. Thank you.

Comment: Also, if you're on Windows you should explore Symlinks which let you link two directories together, that way you can write your code in a different directory than where your addons are located

Comment: @Gorgious Awesome. Thanks!

Comment: I wasn't able to run the addon successfully by Putting the folder for my addon in Blender's addon directory didn't, but the solution I eventually found is to to run it using VS Code's "Blender Development" plugin. This seems to be a good approach.